# how to make a link between two files

Tags: r

I have a folder with 100 pdf and I have a list of the names of those 100 pdf files
I am trying to get a link between the folder and the names

The folder names is myfolder (it has 100 pdf files in it)
I have also a myfile.txt with each row corresponds to one of those pdf , just has the name without any .pdf in it

I am trying to make a link using gsub

```
filePaths <- myfile[,1]

myfiles <- gsub("~/Desktop/myfolder", "", gsub(".pdf", "", filePaths))
```

myfiles, I except to be like this imagining the name of the files are file1 to file100

```
/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/file1.pdf
/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/file2.pdf
/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/file3.pdf
.
.
.
/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/file100.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sprintf()` would make this straightforward:

```r
filePaths <- c("file1", "file2", "file3")
filePaths
#> [1] "file1" "file2" "file3"

myfiles <- sprintf("/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/%s.pdf", filePaths)
myfiles
#> [1] "/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/file1.pdf"
#> [2] "/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/file2.pdf"
#> [3] "/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/file3.pdf"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>